# Find a value from a dictionary in python by taking a key from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary. How can I get the value by taking the key from user?

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
```

If the user enters `a` I wanted to print value `'1'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Do you know how to get user input? Do you know how to use a dictionary?

Comment: yes I have tried it but I could not figure out how to search for the key and get the value

Comment: `d[input()]` will do for a start.

Comment: @MikiasHundie You don't "search" for a key; Python does. You should always read the documentation or follow a tutorial first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do for you:

```py
print(p["a"])
```

This prints the number for "a" in the dictionary.

For your program:

```py
d = str(input("Enter what you want: "))
p  = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
print(p[d])
```

If you enter `a`, then you get 1 as output.

Hope this Helps!!!!

Comment: Also, here is a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Just asking, what is this for?

Answer (score 1):

```
user = input('enter a letter')
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
for i in user:
    print(d[I])
```

use this method if your string consist of more then a single character

Answer (score 1):

Define your dictionary:

```
data = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
```

Ask the user for the key using `input()`:

```
key = input('Enter the key: ')
```

If the key is in the dictionary, print the value, otherwise print an error message:

```
if key in data:
    print('The value is:', data[key])
else:
    print('That key is not in the dictionary.')
```